# Меню на bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Делаю меню на bootstrap и появляется такая ошибка, в последний элемент меню слишком длинный, подскажите как исправить?

```
.menu-top {
  background: #77b9d6;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}
.menu-top a {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu-top a:hover {
  background: #055f86;
  color: white;
}
div a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="story " id="slide-1" data-slide="1">
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top col-sm-10  col-sm-offset-1 menu-top text-center">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#slide-2" class="active navbar-brand col-sm-2">text</a>
      <a href="#slide-2-1" class="active navbar-brand col-sm-2">text</a>
      <a href="#slide-2-2" class="active navbar-brand col-sm-2">text</a>
      <a href="#slide-2-3" class="active navbar-brand col-sm-2">text</a>
      <a href="#slide-2-4" class="active navbar-brand col-sm-2">text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: будет гораздо лучше если Вы на скриншоте или на ином примере покажите, что бы Вы хотели получить

Answer (score 1):

Это не последний элемент длинный, это ваш обрамляющий блок растянут по всей ширине экрана. Если на скорую руку то можно сделать так:

```
.navbar-header {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Свойство display-block растягивает родительский элемент по размеру дочернего

Comment: если я использую ваш код,то текст не растягивается по всей длине блока, как исправить сеё положение?

Comment: @ChromeChrome растягивается, [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/3fwp02xs/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61s9Lk2e/ выделяется маленький прямоугульник, а не весь блок, т.е элемент полностью не растянулся

Answer (score 0):

Вам не кажется, что вы просто забыли закрыть тег `<nav>`?